# How to use multiprocessing in jupyter notebook via windows 10

Tags: python, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook

I tried to use multiprocessing for a simple code in windows 10, python2.7 and jupyter notebook. When I run the code the kernel got stack without any errors thrown. I checked the task manager for performance and saw 8 (the number of cores in my CPU) processes running with 0% use of the CPU for each and everyone of them. 
I looked almost everywhere but didn't find anything. I also tried it in the anaconda prompt but got endless loop of errors.

Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing

n_cpu = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

def foo(x):
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = n_cpu)
    res = pool.map(foo, [1,2,3])  
    pool.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this your actual code? With `foo` being so simple, this code will run so quickly that it's likely to look like 0% CPU usage.

If you see that there are sub-processes spawned, then `pool.map` is doing it's job. If you want to see that all of them actually use full CPU, give them some real meat to chew on (maybe something like `sum([sum(range(x)) for x in range(1000)])`.

Comment: This is not the problem. Even when I give it range(1000000) the kernel got stacked and I get no out.